# What are the english words for positive/negative transactions

Tags: word-choice

To be more specific I am making an app where you can enter your transactions, but I want to differentiate them between when you pay for something (food, tickets, subscriptions) and receive money (paycheck, prize money).

What are the correct words for this ? Maybe for the latter it should be "payment".

Comment: Since it's an app, you could keep it really simple:  "money in" and "money out".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, in accounting, the transactions are referred to as

> **credits** *(additions)*
>   **debits** *(withdrawals)*

For your app, you might use terms non accountants would be familiar with

> **additions**
>   **subtractions**
>
> **incomings**
>   **outgoings**
>
> **received**
>   **spent** or **payments**

They all have the notion of **increasing** and **decreasing** an account